# Configure CORS policy for Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, cors, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have Spring Cloud gateway running on separate server with the following configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/*]':   (I also tried '[/**]':)
            allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:3000"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
```

But every time from React app I get:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://11.1.1.1:8080/api/support/tickets/create' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Do you know how this issue an be solved for Spring Boot 2.6.2/Spring cloud 2021.0.0?

Full code: http://www.github.com/rcbandit111/Spring_Cloud_Gateway_POC

POST Request:

```
Request URL: http://1.1.1.1:8080/api/merchants/onboarding/bank_details
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36

Post request Payload:
{"currency":"HNL","iban":"dssvsdvsdv"}
```

OPTIONS request:

```
Request URL: http://1.1.1.1:8080/api/merchants/onboarding/bank_details
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 1.1.1.1:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
content-length: 0
```

OPTIONS Request headers:

```
OPTIONS /api/merchants/onboarding/bank_details HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.1.1.1:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: Have  you checked allowedOrigins's value is correct ?

Comment: What does the request look like?

Comment: If you're hoping to get an answer to your question, you should add details about the kind of request that your frontend sends to `http://11.1.1.1:8080/api/support/tickets/create`, including its HTTP method and headers.

Comment: I added request data from Chrome's console.

Comment: Do you need this specific for the Spring Boot 2.6.2/Spring cloud 2021.0.0 Version or in general?

Comment: I need this in general for latest stable release. But you can show me several cases.

Comment: I add my solution for an older Version below as answer.

Comment: Any idea is it going to work for latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running your FE app via --proxy-conf to redirect? I am not a well versed in FE, but dont use changeOrigin: true. If you have to to use changeOrigin: true, it will only work for GET and for others you might have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802324/proxy-changeorigin-setting-doesnt-seem-to-work/58752889#58752889).
To use proxy-conf, we usually have a `proxy.conf.json` with something like this:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://external-gateway-url",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

and then while running the app use `--proxy-config proxy.conf.json`. My FE knowledge is out-of-date. You may want to look something like [this](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347).

If not, and the call is direct, just the following configuration (also needed for proxy too) in gateway should work:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:3000"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
```

Comment: no, I don't use ` --proxy-conf`

Comment: So your java script is configured with the host name as well? Meaning in the network tab, call is made from localhost:3000 to gateway http://1.1.1.1:8080?

Comment: I notice, you dont have `allowedHeaders: "*"` in the configuration

Comment: Strange, again it's not working. Can I invite you tomorrow on a call and share my screen to show you in details the issue? Can you share your mail for example, please?

Comment: Not sure about the call, its weekend :)
Can you try using proxy-conf? I will update the answer

Comment: I found the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637808/disable-options-request-before-post-in-react Any idea for a solution?

Comment: OPTIONS is something that browser do when there is a call made to a different origin. Dont think you can control that. You can check the repose-headers from the options call to verify if Gateway is configured correctly.

Comment: If Gateway is not under your control, you could look into using --proxy-conf, a feature by webpack. CORS is a browser-to-server check. Its doesnt happend with backend-to-backend calls. With proxy, you will just re making calls to the webpack server which in turn will be redirecting it to an external server.

Comment: The issue is a bug in Spring Cloud Gateway - OPTIONS requests are blocked so this breaks POST and DELETE requests.

Comment: See here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/112 and here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2472

Comment: Not sure if its a bug. You could wait for spring team to respond. But note that
CORS check kicks in when there is a "Origin" header in the request.  For GET I dont thinks it's their, but for POST/PUT it is typically there.  Enble wiretab logs in gateway to check - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#wiretap

Comment: With postman things, will work fine as its not a bowser call, which adds these headers.

Comment: I send API requests from React app to remote VPS server - CORS should be blocking requests only if all apps are on the same machine.

Comment: Yes with POSTMAN I can make successful POST and DELETE requests.

Comment: Check about origin - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin
If anything in domain changes, its a different origin

Comment: Just enable wiretap logs and check Origin header when the reques is from browser vs when it is from postman.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar Problem and i did the following:

My application.yml contains to add the CORS Configuration to every route:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        add-to-simple-url-handler-mapping: true
```

Then I configured a spring standard CorsWebFilter Bean. Note for production you should not use * for the AllowedOrigins property. For Development purpose this is perfectly fine.

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration extends org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CorsWebFilter corsFilter() {
    org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"));
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("origin");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("content-type");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("accept");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("authorization");
    corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("cookie");
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
    return new CorsWebFilter(source);
  }
}
```

Note: I have the Version 2.3.9.Release for spring boot and spring cloud version is Hoxton.SR10 .

Comment: I tried the code but I get https://pastebin.com/72REGwi8 with latest stable Spring Cloud. Any idea for a solution?

Comment: I expect that * is not allowed anymore. So maybe try `corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigin("<your web adress, e.g. localhost>")`

Comment: One additional question: I run Spring Cloud Gateway on a remote  VPS server and I run run React application on my local PC. I think in that case CORS should not make a problem. Did you had a such case?

Comment: I'm not realy sure about it. But if it is a problem then you may consider running an second gateway on your local machine. So your traffic look like: react app -> local gateway (Here you have to configure cors. Different ports on localhost are different origins!) -> gateway on VPS server.

Comment: Maybe I need to configure something in React app?

Comment: There's never a need to allow the `origin` or `cookie` request headers. Moreover, you cannot use the wildcard (`*`) in conjunction with credentialed requests; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue I set up the following config for my Spring Cloud Gateway

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://127.0.0.1:3000,http://127.0.0.1:3001"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - DELETE
              - PUT
              - OPTIONS
```

I reached this solution from this discussion: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/840

Note that you need to add the default-filters configuration to fix the following issue:

> ":has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header contains multiple values 'http://127.0.0.1:3000,
> [http://127.0.0.1:3000'](http://127.0.0.1:3000%27), but only one is allowed."

Answer (score 2):

You can add the cors configuration in your security class. Like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private SecurityRepository securityRepository;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http){
        http
                .cors().configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
                    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
                    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
                    return configuration;
                });
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me because EnableWebFluxSecurity cannot be found.

Comment: Have you added the spring security dependency in your pom file?

Comment: No, that is the thing. Why would you add an entire dependency just for some small functionality? What if you only want CORS without Spring security because these 2 things are completely independant of each other. Spring security is user security where as CORS is a kind of connection security.

Comment: For the answer I posted to work, you’ll need the security dependency but I think there are other ways to go about it without the dependency

Comment: @Abd Qadr, This option doesn't work for me even with the annotation enabled. You don't have a link to the working code, I don't understand what's the matter?

Comment: checkout this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-cors

Comment: Thanks. This is the only required and correct configuration for me when I use spring cloud gateway as oauth2 resource server.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [Tr1monster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10899197/tr1monster) works and is likely the best approach.

A slightly more compact version of the Java configuration:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig 
    extends CorsConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public CorsWebFilter corsFilter()
    {
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials( true );
        config.setAllowedOrigins( List.of( "*" ) );
        config.setAllowedMethods( List.of( "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD" ) );
        config.setAllowedHeaders( List.of( "origin", "content-type", "accept", "authorization", "cookie" ) );

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration( "/**", config );

        return new CorsWebFilter( source );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [section entitled *Simple requests*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests) in the [MDN Web Docs about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> The only type/subtype combinations allowed for the media type specified in the `Content-Type` header are:
>
> - `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
> - `multipart/form-data`
> - `text/plain`

Because you use the value `application/json` for your request's `Content-Type` header, you need to allow that header in your CORS configuration:

```yaml
cors-configurations:
  '[/**]':
    allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:3000"
    allowedMethods:
      - GET
      - POST
    allowedHeaders:
      - Content-Type
```

Comment: Do you know how I can configure this using Java Bean configuration?

Comment: @PeterPenzov No. That would be a different question anyway.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Have you tried the solution above?

Comment: I will try it later today and let you know hat is the result.

Comment: I get again `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://1.1.1.1:8080/api/merchants/onboarding/countries' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Well, that's progress: no mention of the preflight this time, which means it succeeded. Now the actual request is failing, for some reason. Can you add a screenshot of the response to the actual (`POST`) request?

Comment: Please see this post description: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70561543/configure-cors-policy-for-spring-cloud-gateway I added the payload there

Comment: @PeterPenzov You haven't added the response to the POST request. Based on the error message you're now getting, you should now get a response to that request.

Comment: I will make again later today test requests and let you know about the result.

Answer (score 1):

After lost hours, I did this:

spring:
application:
name: gateway
cloud:
loadbalancer:
ribbon:
enabled: false

```
gateway:
  default-filters:
    - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin
  globalcors:
    corsConfigurations:
      '[/**]':
        allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:3000/"
        allowedHeaders: "*"
        allowedMethods:
          - GET
          - POST
          - DELETE
          - PUT
          - PATCH
  routes:
    - id: service-auth
      uri: lb://service-auth
      predicates:
        - Path=/api/v1/auth/**
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to share with you the solution that worked for me hoping to help whoever is facing the same issue:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        CorsConfiguration cors_config = new CorsConfiguration();
        cors_config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        cors_config.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        cors_config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000", "null"));
        cors_config.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET","POST","OPTIONS","DELETE"));
        cors_config.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));

        http.cors().configurationSource(source -> cors_config)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()//Setting Oauth2Login
                .authenticationSuccessHandler(new RedirectServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler("<MyLogoutURL>")).and()
                .logout(logout -> logout //Setting Oauth2Logout
                        .logoutHandler(logoutHandler())
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()));
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler =
                new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);
        // Sets the location that the End-User's User Agent will be redirected to
        // after the logout has been performed at the Provider
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("http://google.com");
        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
    }

    private DelegatingServerLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        //Invalidate session on logout
        return new DelegatingServerLogoutHandler(
                new SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler(), new WebSessionServerLogoutHandler());
    }
}
```

Be sure to have cors enabled on Keycloak too, navigate to
`realm->clients->settings->weborigins`
and submit your permitted origins.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently and this approach resolved it...

```
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {

//properties

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
            .allowedHeaders(allowedHeaders)
            .allowedMethods(allowedMethods)
            .allowCredentials(allowCredentials)
            .maxAge(maxAge);
   }
}
```