# Configure CORS for Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a React application which is running locally and Spring Cloud Gateway as BE running on a remote VPS. I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://11.1.1.5:8080/api/business_structure' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried to configure CORS in Spring Cloud Gateway:

***application.yml***

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service
  cloud:
   gateway:
    globalcors:
     cors-configurations:
      '[/*]':
        allowedOrigins:
          - "*"
          - "http://localhost:3000"
        allowedMethods:
          - GET
          - POST
```

But it's not working. I'm interested why I get this error in my case? FE and BE are running on different hosts.

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I configured it by defining a new bean `CorsConfigurationSource` which is used. For example:

```java
  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration apiCorsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
    apiCorsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    apiCorsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    apiCorsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    apiCorsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", apiCorsConfiguration);
    return source;
  }
```

But I think that your configuration is wrong. You have there `'[/*]':` but it should be `'[/**]':`

Comment: I tested the code but for some reason it's not working.

Comment: Full code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Spring_Cloud_Gateway_POC

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an extra * is missing. Something like

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://mywebsite.com"
            allowedHeaders: "*"
            allowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
            - PUT
```

Also are you running your FE app via --proxy-conf to redirect? I am not a well versed in FE, but dont use `changeOrigin: true`. If you have to to use `changeOrigin: true`, it will only work for GET and for others you might have to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802324/proxy-changeorigin-setting-doesnt-seem-to-work/58752889#58752889).

Comment: I get `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://1.1.1.1.:8080/api/merchants/onboarding/currencies' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Do you know some other solution? The the thing is that I run the FE React app on my local PC and Spring Cloud Gateway on separate server. CORS should not block it.

Comment: Quick update: I get this error only for POST request. GET reqest are working fine.

Comment: I only got this kind of scenario, when I was using --proxy-conf when running my angular app. Are you sure about the package.json script, thats its not using any proxy?

Comment: Yes, this is the content of package.json file: https://pastebin.com/021R4emp

Comment: If the call is direct from browser, the configuration should work IMO.
Can you also add `allowedHeaders: "*"` in gateway configuration and check